# SharpSvn - Lock file status

Tags: sharpsvn

i am using SharpSvn.dll for my own application. 
one of my goals is to lock file (i am using GetLock() function).
however i did not found a way to know the file status - is it lock or not
regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a file is locally locked you can use `SvnClient.Status()`. If you want to check it at the repository you can use `SvnClient.List()`, but there you have to pass `.RetrieveLocks` as `True` on the SvnListArgs instance.